# How to add default text in output to filled fields in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, webforms, contact-form-7, contact-form

I want to create a form in contact form 7 that is able to change the response in a filled field to standard text in the output email.

The form is - for example -  about buying/selling cars. In the label there's a question "are you looking for a car at the moment?. In the field there is a dropdown menu yes/no. The output in the e-mail should either be "this prospect is planning to buy a car" or "this person isn't interested in buying a car, but he filled in the form so this could be a buyer in the future". In other words, the answer in the filled field is converted to a different text.

Is there any way to do that? I fiddled around with CF7, but cannot get it to work properly. Unfortunately, Im not a programmer, just someone who wants to make a contact form. Can anyone help me here?

Help is appreciated!

Best regards, Max

I tried to fix this with Conditional Logic/conditional field, but this is obviously not a solution.